# IntelliJ Idea showing percentages next to classes - how do I disable this?

Tags: intellij-idea

This screenshot says it all ... I don't know why these percentages just started showing up, and I don't know how to get rid of them... anyone know?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The percentage is the test coverage.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-test-with-coverage.html#read-coverage%20report

You need to open coverage window and close it.
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is "Test Coverage" and why would anyone want that?

Comment: Some measurements to show, how many code is covered by unit tests.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage

Answer (score 1):

- Run action (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>)/(<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>)
- Type `code coverage actions` and select
- Select `Hide Coverage`